# ionChange event doesn't work on ion-select

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework

I want to execute a codeblock every time the value of my `ion-select` changes.
The documentation provides an `ionChange` event for that.
When I try to execute it, nothing happens.
I tried `ionFocus` and it works but i need the `ionChange` event to work.

```
<ion-select @ionChange="changeUnit('ionChange')" @ionFocus="changeUnit('ionFocus')" interface="popover" placeholder="required">
    <ion-select-option value="m3">m3</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value="m2">m2</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value="ml">ml</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value="kg">kg</ion-select-option>
</ion-select>

changeUnit(value){
    console.log(value);
}
```

Do I miss something? Why does the `ionFocus` work but the `ionChange` not?

I'm using ionic 5 and vue 3.

I also use an emitter from `mitt` in the same component.
But this also doesn't interfere with the `ionFocus` event.

Comment: I tested your code using both `method` and `setup` ways. it works without problem. so weird

Answer (score 5, accepted):

make sure you have imported and added to components

```
IonSelect,
IonSelectOption
```

Comment: Bruhhh. Feel like the biggest programming noob on the planet xD. Thank you so much!

Comment: This is caused me bourse of concern in the past, I now always code with the debug console open in the browser so I can catch the warnings